# Email Notification

Tags: email, leads

My user wants to get an email notification every time a lead or contact in his name viewed any marketing material our organization sent them.

Currently I believe that information is updated in the lead or contact but unless he goes into it there is no way of him knowing. So is there anyway I could enable email notification for that user so that he gets the email when a lead or contact opens marketing material in our organization.

Comment: So you want to send an email notification every time the Lead or Contact is viewed? And viewed by whom?